# Error validating ssl certificate for svc.IP.my.local-ip.co in ingress

Tags: nginx-ingress

I try use certificate and DNS http://my.local-ip.co/ in Kubernetes.

I download certificate and key. Create ingress-tls secret.

```
kubectl create secret tls ingress-tls --key /tmp/server.key --cert /tmp/bundled_cert_file.pem
```

Try install kubernetes dashboard by helm with ingress-tls secret:

```
helm install kube-dashboard --set ingress.enabled=true \
--set protocolHttp=true \
--set service.externalPort=9090 \
--set ingress.tls[0].secretName=ingress-tls \
--set ingress.tls[0].hosts[0]=kubernetes-dashboard.10-66-218-100.my.local-ip.co \
--set ingress.hosts[0]=kubernetes-dashboard.10-66-218-100.my.local-ip.co \
--set extraArgs="{--enable-insecure-login=true,--enable-skip-login=true,--disable-settings-authorizer=true,--insecure-bind-address=0.0.0.0,--insecure-port=9090}" \
kubernetes-dashboard/kubernetes-dashboard
```

But ingress get error:

```
SSL certificate "default/ingress-tls" does not contain a Common Name or Subject Alternative Name for server "kubernetes-dashboard.10-66-218-100.my.local-ip.co": x509: certificate is valid for *.my.local-ip.co, not kubernetes-dashboard.10-66-218-100.my.local-ip.co
```

How disable validating SSL certificate?
Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my wildcard SSL certificate cause a domain mismatch error on a second level subdomain?](https://serverfault.com/questions/645230/why-does-my-wildcard-ssl-certificate-cause-a-domain-mismatch-error-on-a-second-l)

Comment: Thanks for answer. But this is not answer for my question.

Comment: Yes, it is. It explains exactly what has happened and why you cannot do what you have tried to do.

Comment: I think you right. Please answer my question.

Comment: Or may be delete question?